# RRDTool database definition and plotting the data -I need a second opinion

Tags: rrdtool

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
I read my data once a day (the exact time of the day is not very important). 
I want to archive the values for this DS for two years back.
I need to be able to look back for 2 years and I need the value for every day
and I also need to see the weekly average
If I miss a reading for two consecutive days the data should be declared unknown

Here is what I am using for this:

```
rrdtool create Carsforsale.rrd --start 20130217 --step 86400 ^ 
DS:MidsizeCars:GAUGE:172800:U:U ^ 
DS:FullSizeCars:GAUGE:172800:U:U ^ 
RRA:AVERAGE:0:7:104^ 
RRA:LAST:0:7:1:720
```

I updated the above database with

```
rrdtool update Carsforsale.rrd 1361203200:554:791
rrdtool update Carsforsale.rrd 1361289600:556:795
```

The updated correspond to yesterday and the day before yesterday (18, 19 Feb)

I tried to plot the graphs for the above using this

```
rrdtool graph "Inventory.png" \
--start "20130217" \
--imgformat PNG --width 850 --height 400 \
DEF:MidsizeCars=Carsforsale.rrd:MidsizeCars:AVERAGE \
DEF:FullSizeCars=Carsforsale.rrd:FullSizeCars:AVERAGE \
AREA:MidsizeCars#0000FF:"MidsizeCars" \
AREA:FullSizeCars#FF004D:"FullSizeCars:STACK"'
```

And now here are the my questions:

1. are the step and the heart beat defined correctly for what I wantto do ?
2. Why are my graphs empty ?
3. Looking into the database with the freeware utility called RRD Editor I could see that the last values are stored in the MidSizeCars and FullSizecars but the only DS that     contains a history of what has been loaded into the database is the archiving function LAST Am I supposed to plot LAST or Average to see the current values ?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you want to keep the data for two years at 1 day resolution, you have to setup an appropriate RRA for this purpose ... since this will only be about 730 values, I would not bother with setting up an extra consolidated RRA for the week. this will get calculated on the fly ...

Comment: HI Tobi, thanks for taking the time to reply and thanks for the correction, indeed that should be 730 not what I put initially. In the file on my computer that was correct though (730). Sorry for the confusion. That is corrected now. I still can't understand what I am missing when creating the graphs. Is a DS just a buffer for the last value? Why can't I see anything whey I graph DS:Average but I see the graphs when I pgraph DS:LAST ? In your examples you seem to use DS: Average just fine. http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph_examples.en.html.

Comment: This creates the graphs that I expect, the above **doesn't** :-(    'rrdtool graph "Inventory.png" \
--start "20130217" \
--imgformat PNG --width 850 --height 400 \
DEF:MidsizeCars=Carsforsale.rrd:MidsizeCars:LAST \
DEF:FullSizeCars=Carsforsale.rrd:FullSizeCars:LAST \
AREA:MidsizeCars#0000FF:"MidsizeCars" \
AREA:FullSizeCars#FF004D:"FullSizeCars:STACK"'

Comment: using LAST rarely makes sense ... as I said, you have to config your RRA to store at every step ... the DS does not store anything ... it simply defines the input.

Comment: Thanks Tobi, for writing this great piece of software and for answering my questions!